# 1NF Normal Form with Functional Dependecy

Tags: database, normalization, database-normalization, denormalization, bcnf

I read following example, that relation A(X,Y,Z,P,Q,R) with the following functional dependency.

why this is in 1NF?

[image]

anyone could help me?

Comment: See [First normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) - 1NF basically says "no sequences/collections as values". The FD does *not* even apply to 1NF.

Comment: Dear @user2864740, yes, i read it, but about this one i confused !! would you please learn me with this example ?

Comment: 1NF is entirely dependent that the attributes of a relation is atomic. From just looking at FD's we don't know if it's in 1NF or not. But we can see it does not meet the requirements for being in 2NF.

Comment: Dear @SpencerWieczorek, Which condition violate 2NF? how we can say in 1NF?

Comment: @MioMio I was assuming that the PK is *P* or *PY*, but I may be wrong. Could you tell me what the PK is?

Comment: Dear @SpencerWieczorek, someone say on of probably PK is  {x,y} and some one say {Y,P}

Comment: @MioMio In both cases it's not 2NF since every non-key isn't dependent on the PK.

Comment: Dear @SpencerWieczorek,  Would you please submit as an answer with some detail? how about 1NF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diagram is not normal notation. I suppose that arrows point to determined attributes of FDs. I suppose that an arrow that doesn't come from a box means a FD with just one determinant attribute and an arrow that comes from a box means a FD with the boxed attributes as determinant attributes. *Find out what the diagram notation means.*

If so then the functional dependencies are Y → Z, XYZ → QR and P → QRX.

To show what normal form the relation is in we need to know what definitions you were given for normal forms. It happens that this relation is not in 2nd normal form. So it isn't in any higher normal form. So it is only in 1st normal form. So the only normal form definition we need to know is the one you were given for 2NF. That definition usually involves candidate keys. If so then we need to know what definition you were given for candidate key. The definition of 2NF can involve full and partial FDs. If yours does then we need to know what definitions of full and/or partial FD you were given. *Give the definitions.*

The only CK is PY because it determines every other attribute but no proper subset of it does. It is the only CK because there is no other such set of attributes. To justify this we need to reference the rules you were given for deriving FDs and CKs. (Eg this includes how we went from one FD list to another.) *Give the rules.*

But there are then also determinants Y (from Y → Z) and P (from P → QRX) that are proper subsets of that candidate key.  So each of non-prime attributes Z, Q, R and X is partially dependent on a CK. But to be in 2NF there must be no non-prime attributes partially dependent on a candidate key. Ie every non-prime attribute must be fully functionally dependent on all CKs. So A is not in 2NF. So the highest normal form it is in is 1NF.

Answer (score 1):

The picture doesn't make its meaning very clear in my opinion because it seems to be mixing two different notations for functional dependencies (FDs). Any answer will depend on how you want to interpret the diagram.

I'd hazard a guess that the diagram is supposed to indicate the following set of FDs: XY->Z, Y->QR, P->QRX. If that's correct then the possible candidate key respecting that set of FDs would be {Y,P}. If my interpretation of the diagram is correct then both Y and P are determinants in their own right. Since Y and P are proper subsets of a candidate key of A we can conclude that A violates 2NF and therefore the highest normal form that A can satisfy is 1NF.

---

Update: Your new picture specifies some dependencies. Collecting the determinant terms together we can summarize as:

```
P->XQR
XY->QR
Y->Z
```

I assume these are supposed be the dependencies actually satisfied by A. On the left-hand side we have P, X and Y so PXY will be a superkey of A. P->X therefore the candidate key (minimal superkey) can only be PY. P->XQR and Y->Z are both FDs with determinants that are proper subsets of the candidate key (PY) and that means those dependencies both violate 2NF. Recap: 2NF prohibits any FD where the left-hand side is a proper subset of a candidate key. So 1NF is the highest normal form of A.

Comment: Both diagrams look a bit strange. In the second diagram P->X is specified as a dependency and X is also supposed to be a determinant. It isn't clear to me which lines represent those dependencies. I suspect either the diagram is misleading or the list of FDs is wrong.

Comment: Dear @sqlvogel, i think the  firs part of your answer (before Update) is correct one. are u agree with me? i think my instructor is wrong.

Comment: Ask your instructor. I'm not confident because the diagrams are too ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

As per 1NF, no two rows of a relation must have repeating values and no column must have more than one value in a row. This increases redundancy as there will be columns with same data repeating in many rows.

```
Name    ID       Course

A       1       Computer
B       2        Arts
C       3       Computer
```

Here Course column has repeated values. But every row has no column which has 2 values. Hence it is in 1NF.

1NF has the least number of restrictions. So any other forms like 2NF, 3NF by default would also be in 1NF.

Consider this analogy

```
1NF = Living Beings
2NF = Mammals
3NF = Humans
```

All mammals/2NF are by default living beings/1NF, and so on.

To satisfy the functional dependency `X → Y`, it is essential that each X value be associated with only one Y value. And thus it satisfies the 1NF criteria which does not allow multiple values in a row for a column.

Comment: you means just is 1NF? what about 2NF? and more...? would you please add a bit detail.

Comment: If an attribute is functionally dependent on the entire candidate key and not its subset (just a part of the key) and it is in 1NF, only then it is in 2NF. 

As per my understanding of your relation A, here, all attributes i.e. P and X,Y,Z seem to be dependent on Q and R entirely and not just Q or R. Hence, it is in 2NF.

For 3NF, all non key attributes must be dependent ONLY on the Primary key and the table must be in 2NF.

Here Y is dependent on Z which is not a primary key and hence the relation A(X,Y,Z,P,Q,R) is not in 3NF.